# How to enable all STIX font glyphs in Firefox?

Tags: fonts, firefox

I'd like to try using the [STIX fonts](http://stixfonts.org/) as my main web font while browsing in Firefox on Arch Linux. After installing the [package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/otf-stix/) (which currently includes the latest release, 1.1.1) I get a bunch more fonts in Firefox, and I've tried a few of them. Every time the [official glyphs page](http://www.stixfonts.org/allGlyphs.html) reports

> One or more STIX (scientific) fonts are not installed on your computer. Please install ALL the STIX version 1.0 fonts.

Looking at the page with "STIX MathJax Normal" as the default font it seems that some glyphs from several fonts are missing. A couple examples (dozens of glyphs are in fact missing):

- 0E08B ("stix-greater-than or (contour) similar") from `stixnonuni.otf` is missing, but not 0E17C ("stix-Mathematical sans-serif partial differential") from the same file.
- 0E154 ("stix-oblique open face capital letter A") from `stixnonuniita.otf` is missing, but not 0E1B4 ("stix-Mathematical sans-serif italic digit 0") from the same file.

My questions:

1. How can I have *some* glyphs but not all from the same file?
2. Does version 1.1.1 not have all the glyphs which were available in 1.0?
3. Has anyone been able to satisfy the glyphs page script with Firefox on Linux? If so, how?

I would ask the STIX Fonts project, but the web site says "Please direct any questions or general comments to the STIX Fonts project.", where "STIX Fonts project" is a JavaScript pop-up link to a [page](http://www.aip.org/stixfonts/contact.jsp?eid=205) which reports a proxy error "DNS lookup failure for: tconnell.devcloud.acquia-sites.comstixfonts".